# Countif a active range and not a predefined range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find and return the number of times the word “overflow” appears in an active range in Excel.How do I search in the active selected range and not a predefined range like  A1:A50

```
Dim MyCount As Long
MyCount = Application.Countif(Range("A1:A50"),"Oveflow")
MsgBox "I have completed my search and found  " & MyCount & " cell(s)."
```

Is it possible to perform countif on active selected range ?

Comment: do you wanna count as 2 if one cell have repeated overflow for twice ? if yes, countif may not working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `Selection` in VBA to reference the range that you actually have selected :

```
Dim MyCount As Long
MyCount = Application.Countif(Selection,"Oveflow")
MsgBox "I have completed my search and found  " & MyCount & " cell(s)."
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property is the cell or range of cells in the current selection.

```
MyCount = Application.Countif(Selection,"Oveflow")
```

That will return the count from the currently selected cells containing **Oveflow**<sup>[sic]</sup>.

---

<sub>More examples of using the [Application.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property (not Select) can be found in [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/28700020#28700020)</sub>.